# Using Excel with Silverlight app not writing new columns

Tags: silverlight, excel

I have a project as follows:
User uploads Excel file to server, server will return back with 2 new columns. User wants us to check prices being charged and we have file that holds average standard pricing.

In the desktop application just done, I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
for manipulating  the Excel file.

But this is not available in Silverlight.  Reading is not the issue.

The issue is adding 2 new columns. Program reads excel file using oledb,  and oledb is very light and is available in web.

But for creating 2 new columns,  I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel  that Microsoft provides.

This is not available in web.

I will be need to check how can we do this.

One possibility is to have the program on the server, waiting for a file, process the file, and email back to the user.

I just want to see if there is another way. I don't like this approach it doesn't seem best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options for doing this with Silverlight. First, you can use the [Excel XML format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats) for the files which means adding a column is just an XML exercise. Second, if that doesn't work, you can [upload the file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to the server and run the same code you have in your desktop app to update the file. Once it is updated you can prompt the user to [save the file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.savefiledialog%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) back to their hard drive.

If you go the Excel XML route then you would need to create a web service to get the price data from your database out to the Silverlight on the client. Oledb won't work since you don't want to expose your database via oledb on the Internet.